# How does graph_def store the shape info of input and output of a node

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I downloaded the inception v3 model(a frozen graph) from website and imported it into a session then I found that the shape of inputs and outputs of all nodes in this graph_def are already fully known, but when I freeze my own graph contaning `tf.Examples` queues as inputs, the batch_size info seems to be lost and replaced with a `?`, my question is how I can fix or change the unknown shape when I try to freeze a graph?

edit:

the `node.attr` of some nodes in graph_def contains the shape info but why not all nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each node in the `graph_def` doesn't contains the shape of output tensor, after importing `graph_def` into memory (with tf.import_graph_def), the shape of each tensor in the graph is automatically determined